# Emulating HTML 3 <tab> elements in modern browsers

Tags: html

Html 3 have nice rare feature tabs like in word: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/tabs.html but I can't use this feature in modern browsers.
Is there newer option to format text in paragraph without tables, multi &nbsp and css columns?

I'm trying to make this layout in one paragraph:

```
Price in USD/per kg
A      20$
BBB    30$
CCCCC  40$
```

Thanks!

Comment: Heh, that is a cool feature indeed! Didn't know/remember this. I guess you can work around it using CSS these days, but the best way to go is likely a `<table>`.

Comment: Provide indentation via CSS; `text-indent` property.

Comment: You can use <pre> tag in HTML. This will show text in prefromatted way.

Comment: Use CSS Tables :) Not the creepy standard `<table>`s :)

Comment: The example is tabular data, and as such *should* actually be represented in a `<table>`.

Comment: +1 for the epic argument you've sparked....

Comment: Why not tables? Tables are taboo for layout purposes, but not for their actual intended use. Tabular data should be presented in table format, there cannot be arguments against that.

Comment: Div-based "CSS" tables are a Rube Goldberg machine, broken on so many levels...

Comment: I have to use this paragraph in ckeditor and simulate using tabs like in word with . In html3 tabs there is option to define all paragraphs with distance from left margin and align.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<pre>` tag in HTML. This will show the text in a preformatted way.

Answer (score 3):

HTML 3.0 was an incomplete draft, in the mid-1990s, which was never completed, approved, or implemented (though some manuals and vendors used “HTML 3.0” as a buzzword long after HTML 3.0 draft expired).

Some of the ideas in HTML 3.0 were later developed and adopted into specifications, but the `tab` element was completely abandoned.

You can still use the `pre` element, which has been in HTML since the early days. Within in, formatting is preserved, and TAB characters (horizontal tab, HT, U+0009) takes you to the next tab stop. But the stops are set at every 8th character, in a fixed manner. The proposed [`tab-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/tab-size) property in CSS would let you set the “size” of the TAB character, though, and it has been implemented in several browsers.

However, for the data outlined in the question, an HTML `table` element is clearly the simplest, the most logical, and the most robust way. If your authoring environment does not let you use HTML tables, it won’t let you do much useful in the realm of web authoring in general – in any case, if this is really a problem, you should describe the specific constraints and ask a question about dealing with them, instead of asking about a hypothetical idea abandoned almost 20 years ago.

Comment: I have to simulate MS word like tabs in html to use with CKeditor. Without CK i can use span with margins and vertical alignment.

Comment: @PiotrNowicki, that’s a different problem and should be posted as a separate question.